# Dynamic dropdown list with ajax,sql and php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

> I get a dynamic dropdown by combining config.php, index.php and ajax.php but when i modify the code and use it in another file which include the files config.php, sales.php and ajax.php i don't get the dropdown.
> i have 2 folders folder_1 contains config.php, index.php and ajax.php this gives the desired dropdown list i wanted.
> but in folder_2 i have config.php,sales.php and ajax.php but i did't get the dropdown.
> I copy paste the exact code from folder_1 to folder_2 but the code is not working.

config.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_cafeteria");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#category').change(function(){
 var categoryid = $(this).val();
$('#food').find('option').not(':first').remove();
  // AJAX request
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: { categoryid: categoryid},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
         var len = response.length;
        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
           var id = response[i]['id'];
           var name = response[i]['name'];
             $("#food").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
             }
       }
     });

  });
});  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>category</td>
    <td>
       <!-- Country dropdown -->
       <select id='category' >
          <option value="" >---Select---</option>
          <?php 
          ## Fetch countries
          $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_category ORDER BY categoryname");
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
          {
            echo "<option value='".$row['category_id']."'>".$row['categoryname']."</option>";
          }
          ?>
       </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>food</td>
    <td>
      <select id='food' >
         <option value="" >---Select---</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

    
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

sales.php

```
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#category').change(function(){
 var categoryid = $(this).val();
$('#food').find('option').not(':first').remove();
  // AJAX request
 
     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {categoryid: categoryid},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
         var len = response.length;
         if( len >0 ){
             $("#food").empty();
             $("#food").html('<option value="">---select---</option>');
        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
           var id = response[i]['id'];
           var name = response[i]['name'];
             $("#food").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             $('#food').html('<option value="">No food available</option>');
             }
       }
       
     });

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("config.php");
?>
<form action="stock_reg_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="container" style="margin-left:106px; margin-bottom:10%;padding-left:130px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #1b93e1; border-radius: 4px; top: 14px; padding-top: 5%;">
        <h2 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 6%;font-family: fantasy; padding-right:13%"> ADD PRODUCT STOCK</h2>


    <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right; padding-top:8px;">
        <label>Date</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="stock_date" style="width:500px;" required autofocus>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right; padding-top:8px;">
        <label>Category</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        
         <select required name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control" style="width:500px;" required autofocus>
         </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <option selected disabled value="">---select---</option>
         <?php
         
         $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_category ORDER BY categoryname");
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
         {
           echo "<option value='".$row['category_id']."'>".$row['categoryname']."</option>";
         }
          ?>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right; padding-top:8px;">
        <label>Food</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select  name="food_id" id="food" class="form-control" style="width:500px;" required autofocus>
        <option selected disabled value="">---select---</option>
      </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right">
        <label>Stock Status</label>
      </div>
      
  <label style="margin-left:15px">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" />
  
      <span>ADD</span>

  </label>

  <label style="margin-left:30px">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" />
 
      <span>REMOVE</span>

  </label>

    </div>
     <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right; padding-top:8px;">
        <label>Quantity</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" style="width:500px;" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required autofocus>
      </div>
    </div>
     <br>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align:right; padding-top:8px;">
        <label>Description</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="stock_description" style="width:500px;" placeholder="Enter Description" required autofocus>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
     <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:38%">
    </div>
    <br>
     </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

include "config.php";


// Fetch food list by categoryid

   $categoryid = $_POST['categoryid'];

   $response = array();

   $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_food WHERE category_id='".$_POST["categoryid"]."' ORDER BY food_name");
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
         {
            $id=$row["food_id"];
            $name=$row["food_name"];

            $response[] = array("id" => $id, "name" => $name);
         }
   echo json_encode($response);
   exit;
   ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.